# My flutter app contains with some API calls. After building APK, it's says null value

Tags: flutter, flutter-apk

I have made an app that fetches some data by API.

In my emulator, the app fetches data perfectly and shows the data correctly too.
But whenever I build an APK and install it on my phone the data doesn't show up.

Why is it happening? In the emulator, it's works.

For fetching data, I used future builder

Comment: make sure you added internet permission in the AndroidManofest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

As flutter docs [say on reviewing the app manifest](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest) you should locate your `AndroidManifest.xml` file located in [project]/android/app/src/main.
Then inside `manifest` tag insert Android permission element as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The code above follows the syntax mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element).

According to flutter docs:

> The standard template does not include this tag but allows Internet access during development to enable communication between Flutter tools and a running app.